# Are there any stable $(\infty,1)$-topoi?

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, topos-theory, higher-category-theory

Can a [stable $(\infty,1)$-category](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/stable+%28infinity,1%29-category) be an [$(\infty,1)$-topos](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/%28infinity%2C1%29-topos)?

Comment: Could someone help me and tell why this question is ''off-topic''?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, for essentially the same reason that there are no interesting abelian categories that are also toposes: an abelian category (resp. stable $(\infty, 1)$-category) has a zero object, i.e. an initial object that is also terminal, but initial objects in toposes (resp. $(\infty, 1)$-toposes) are strict, so the only topos (resp. $(\infty, 1)$-topos) that has a zero object is the trivial one.

Answer (score 3):

This is basically Zhen Lin's answer for nontrivial cartesian closed categories: Assume that a nontrivial cartesian closed category $\mathcal{C}$ has a zero object. Then, let $C\in\mathcal{C}$. We would have that $0=0\times C=C$ (the functor $-\times C:\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{C}$ commutes with empty colimits). Thus $\mathcal{C}$ would be a trivial cartesian closed category; hence any nontrivial cartesian closed category cannot have a zero object.